# Set parameter to android webView via javaScript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I need to load localStorage parameter to webView:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        token: localStorage.userToken
    }
});

sendToApp = function(_key, _val) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", _key + ":##sendToApp##" + _val);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);iframe = null;
}

IsMobile = true;

$.when(

    loadData.setup()

).then(function(data) {

    Setup = data;

    Struct = new App.Collection.Struct();
    View = new App.View.Phone();
    Zone = new App.Collection.Zone();

    Zone.setAll();
    Zone.findWhere({id:"0"}).set('path', 'Favourites')
    Struct.startLoop();
});
```

My code looks like that:

```
 public void setupWebView(String url, String token) {
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );

        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem(\"userToken\",\"" + token + "\")");
    }
```

What do I need to do to avoid this error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.", source:  (1)
```

My url format is "http://" + addressIp:port + "/m.php". I can access it from my internet PC browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before firing any JavaScript you have to make sure your page is loaded and the window property is available, to do so you can make use of `WebViewClient::onPageFinished` method.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem(\"userToken\",\"" + token + "\")");
    }
});
```